# how i can save true field value in sqlserver?

Tags: c#, sql-server

i want save true value in database,my value is 12.54364878156 but when save in database save 12.54,i want save 12.54364878156 in database

my model class :

```
 public class DividedValue
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title{ get; set; }
    public decimal Result{ get; set; }
 }
```

in my controller :

```
 DividedValue dividedValue = new DividedValue();
 dividedValue.Title = "";
 dividedValue.Result = 12.54364878156m;
 dbContext.add(dividedValue);
 dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

but save 12.54 in database

Comment: Check datatype of the column. It may accept the data up to 2 decimal only.

Comment: please increase your datatype decimal point value

Comment: You need to [understand precision and scale](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql)

Comment: Like the others have said, you need to incrase the amount of decimals places you are storing. This is called the precision. When declaring a decimal you need to provide 2 parameters, for example: `decimal(12,10)`. This is the scale is 12 (it can store up to 12 digits) with a precision up to 10 (10 decimal places). I don't know how high your numbers are going to go to (how how accurate), but, based on your sample number, I'd suggest at least something like `decimal(20,12)`. That *should* more than cover you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just change result field Data Type from
 decimal(18, 2) to decimal(18, 12) or more
 in your table in database

```
decimal(18, n) // n=Number of decimal places
```